# fire a fuction after render wight

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi I have a custom Widget that I'm building and I'm look for a way to fire a function after my Widget get rendered . "NOT BEFORE NOT DURING "
because I wanna use some globalKeys that I had saved during the rendering time

Comment: Check `addPostFrameCallback` in `initState()` . Reference to the [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-lifecycle-for-android-and-ios-developers-8f532307e0c7) .